# Map Reduce array to string

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a array map function which helps me reduce an array of objects down to a simple string.

```
const formatEmails: (arr: { "default" : string }[]) => string = (arr: { "default" : string }[]) => 
arr.map(e => e["default"]).reduce((e, i) => e + i + "; ", "");
```

this outputs me the actual email address with out the default. But what if my email looks like this and does not only have default as a key ?

```
 person_emails: [{ "default": 'test1@test.com' }, { "home": 'test2@test.com' }, { "work": 'test3@test.com' }]
```

How would i go about that and how can i generate a string of for example 
**"default:test1@test.com; home:test2@test.com; work:test3@test.com"**

Also just to be clear my code calls the function formatEmails everytime we read a row on the data export like this

```
args.rowData["person_emails"] = formatEmails(args.rowData["person_emails"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply join the object entries

```js
const person_emails = [{ "default": 'test1@test.com' }, { "home": 'test2@test.com' }, { "work": 'test3@test.com' }];
const res = person_emails.map(e => 
  Object.entries(e).map(en => en.join(':')).join('; ')
).join('; ');
console.log(res);
```

Above works also for multiple pairs in a single object

Comment: Yes that works as a standalone, but in my case what would i change the line const formatEmails: (arr: { "default" : string }[]) => string = (arr: { "default" : string }[]) => 
arr to as i no longer need to descibe the array ? Also i am getting an error on Object.entries(e) saying Properties 'entries' does not exist on 'ObjectConstructor'